# IMFTransform::ProcessInput not returning samples before over 25 have been submitted

Tags: c#, c++, ms-media-foundation

A bit at a loss attempting to decode an H264 stream using Windows Media Foundation and IMF.

I found that even with an H264 stream defining a `max_num_ref_frames` of 2, IMFTransform will require to be input over 25 frames before it output anything, and `IMFTransfer::Input` will return each time `MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT`.

Should I drain the decoder, then they all come out ; but the problem with that is that it means it won't be able to decode any new samples between the last one returned and the next keyframe.

With a `max_num_ref_frames` of 2 (for info:

```
max_num_ref_frames specifies the maximum number of short-term and
long-term reference frames, complementary reference field pairs,
and non-paired reference fields that may be used by the decoding
process for inter prediction of any picture in the
sequence.)
```

The decoder would only need to buffer a maximum of 2 frames. And regardless, the maximum that could ever be required with H264 is 16 frames.

Setting the IMFTransform with `CODECAPI_AVLowLatencyMode` property (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will help ; but this is only available on Windows 8 and isn't a generic solution as it can't handle B-frames properly).

Any suggestions ?
TIA

Comment: I dont remember by heart but which NAL bytestream format does MF accept? Could it be that it cannot determine the boundaries of the NAL units and thus does not give any output? Since 25 most likely is the GOP length, have you set the keyframe sample flags properly?

Comment: It takes AnnexB as input. We add the SPS and PPS NAL before each keyframe. How would you set the keyframe sample flags ? I see that it only takes the data and the timestamp. I was under the assumption that it extract that flag from the NALs themselves.

Comment: So, even after setting the MFSampleExtension_CleanPoint attribute so it properly is told that the sample is a keyframe ; still same deal :(. Thank you very much for the pointer though

Comment: well, a stupid question, but are you sure that `max_num_ref_frames` is 2 ? Maybe you should try and parse the PPS to verify? If you also perform the encoding then I guess there is no need, as you know the settings, but if the stream is coming from somewhere else, it might be worth checking since there are other parameters like `max_dec_frame_buffering` that could impact this. Do you have a bitstream example that causes this behaivor?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure. I retrieve the value by parsing the SPS directly. Using other decoders (different platforms), the decoded data comes out as expected. I'll post a link to a video soon.

Comment: Here is a video: https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/raw-file/b12a261ee32e/dom/media/mediasource/test/bipbop/bipbop2s.mp4 max_num_ref_frames is 2. I don't decode the max_dec_frame_buffering from the parameter, I'm not sure what it's set up as (the video is encoded with FFmpeg)

Comment: Would there be away for the WMF to return the frames in decoded order (like what Apple VideoToolbox does) ; I could do the reordering myself then and not be bound to the whim of WMF.. Btw, thank you heaps for your help.. very much appreciated

Comment: Settting the CODECAPI_AVLowLatencyMode property helped greatly in Windows 8. I now see frames coming out much quicker; unfortunately it doesn't work with vista or Win7 (without SP1)